# No sound in Debian 7

Tags: audio, intel

I've installed Debian 7 but there is no sound. The motherboard is H110M-D D3. Is there any way besides upgrading the kernel to make the audio work?

I've tried the most common solutions (mute in alsamixer, pulseaudio is running). A driver is loaded for the audio as far as I can see:

```
    lspci -k | grep -iA5 audio
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86c7
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: How are you testing for sound? Are you sure there is no hardware issue? Does the sound work on a live session or other OS?

Comment: Fire up `pavucontrol` to start with, and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: There is no hardware problem, I've tested it with the newest Ubuntu and it works.

Comment: `pavucontrol` says everything is ok, even the sound bar moves when music is playing, but there is no output from the sound card. I guess an upgrade to newer linux kernel is necessary but I was hoping there is a way not to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest kernel, the easiest way in debian/ubuntu is to download the .deb packages built by ubuntu kernel team. For Linux 4.5 64bits:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb
```

Then, you must reboot and choose the new kernel during boot in the grub menu.

Comment: One should anyone do this? An `apt-get` update and upgrade is not enough?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was asking if there is a way besides upgrading the kernel.

Comment: I think that upgrading the kernel could solve it, the latests versions have a lot of new features and support for intel hardware.